# Example of algebraic equivalence of cycles?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to understand the algebraic equivalence of cycles. Can someone provide me with a simple example of two cycles on a variety that are algebraically equivalent, but are not rationally equivalent? I can't find an explicit example when I search about it in google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be an curve of positive genus and consider two distinct points $x_1,x_2$ on $X$. Then $x_1$ and $x_2$ are not rationally equivalent, as the only curve with linearly equivalent points is $\Bbb P^1$. On the other hand, the diagonal divisor $\Delta \subset X\times X$ is an effective Cartier divisor which restricts to $x_1$ on the first factor over $x_1$ on the second factor and $x_2$ on the first factor over $x_2$ on the second factor, so $x_1$ and $x_2$ are algebraically equivalent.